# How do I compare all rows in a columns incrementally but also group them at the same time in access?

Tags: ms-access, compare, rows, difference

This is the table that I would like to compare the values within the row groups incrementally however I would not like to compare rows amongst groups as it would come with negative values.[image]

How do I achieve this on the same table? I am unfamiliar with subqueries

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need is a **Calculated Field** added as a third column to your table. 
Instructions:

1. Select the drop down menu next to "*Click to Add*" to create a new column.
2. From the choices available select **Caluculated Field** and then **Number**.
3. The Expression Builder will open.
4. All you need to do from there is select the column you want to use as your primary number (in your case **Number**) from the Expression Categories, insert a minus sign, then select the number you want to subtract from the first number (in your case **Group**), again in the Expression Categories.
5. Name the column you created whatever you would like.

Comment: Hello I dont want to minus group to number. I want to compare the difference in value from the previous row (number).

Comment: Ok. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I'm pretty sure Access doesn't really work like that as the individual rows have no fixed order in a table and there is no way to reference a specific record without a primary ID. Do you have to do this in Access or can you use Excel?